# Complex Regex Help - understanding {} within this statement

Tags: regex, sed

I have a regex I'm trying to understand. I think I have most of it but I'm lost in respect to the bit inside the {} below. I *think* it says, if there's not something matching the first part (within the {}) then add the latter part.

I tried to break it down specifically.

```
egrep  "^\s*password\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix.so(\s+.*)$" /etc/pam.d/system-auth && sudo sed -ri '/^\s*password\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix.so\s+/ { /^\s*password\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix.so(\s+\S+)*(\s+remember=[0-9]+)(\s+.*)?$/! s/^(\s*password\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix.so\s+)(.*)$/\1remember=5 \2/ }' /etc/pam.d/system-auth && sudo sed -ri 's/(^\s*password\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix.so(\s+\S+)*\s+)remember=[0-9]+(\s+.*)?$/\1remember=5\3/' /etc/pam.d/system-auth
```

I tried to break it down as follows...

```
if pattern ("^\s*password\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix.so(\s+.*)$")
sed '/^\s*password\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix.so\s+/ { /^\s*password\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix.so(\s+\S+)*(\s+remember=[0-9]+)(\s+.*)?$/! s/^(\s*password\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix.so\s+)(.*)$/\1remember=5 \2/ }'
if success
    sed 's/(^\s*password\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix.so(\s+\S+)*\s+)remember=[0-9]+(\s+.*)?$/\1remember=5\3/'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, it might help to read through the [sed command list](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-commands-list) and [options](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options). Particularly pertaining to `s/regex/replace/[flags]` and `{ cmd ; cmd ... }`.

But you are basically right. The sed command with the {} is basically saying "find a line like `password sufficient pam_unix.so`, and if that line doesn't contain `remember=#`, add `remember=5`".

The final sed then finds all those lines again, and changes `remember=#` to `remember=5`

Comment: thanks! I don't have enough rep to up vote you but I would. If someone else could that would be great.